# PTP (“connect as camera”) no longer working after update

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb-connection-mode

After updating my Samsung Galaxy Nexus to Jelly Bean, PTP no longer works:

When I connect the phone via USB to my MacBook Pro and enable PTP on the phone, it does connect properly as a camera device and is visible as such in iPhoto / Picasa. However, it’s usually displayed as empty, even though there are photos on the phone’s camera, taken both before and after the update, which haven’t yet been synchronised.

Sometimes it’s not empty but the images that *are* transferred are merely thumbnails, not full-resolution photos.

Has anybody else got this problem? Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Incidentally, the import works on Windows using the Windows Live photo managing tool.