# Alternative file transfer clients

Tags: file-transfer, macos

I think most people will agree that [the official file transfer client](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/) for OS X is *painful* to use. It seems to stagnate at version 1.0 and only offers the bare minimum.

Since my [camera connection still isn’t fixed](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25972/14650) I unfortunately have to use it quite frequently.

Are there alternative clients that are better integrated into the operating system or are there any plans to make it obsolete (after all, neither Linux nor Windows require such a client, they can access the storage of the smartphone directly)?

To clarify, I’m not necessarily looking for *more features* but *better integration*. However, anything that makes it easier to use fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go the wireless route I'd recommend Wi-Fi File Explorer pro.
Just make a Tethered WiFi network(or be on the same router) use the app on your phone to get a local IP and transfer all files directly. It needs no installation on your computer; just install it on your phone and use it.

Comment: Hmm. Not perfect (website – why not an SMB share?) but already much better – thanks.